# Review this solar-powered weather station schematic?

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, schematics, solar-energy

It's my first time designing a schematic in EDA (or at all really) and I'd love a review of this schematic to point out any silly general circuit mistakes I might be making. Not looking to dive into functionality, but any general EE considerations (pushbutton circuits, placements of resistors/caps, proper wiring of grounds) that I might have missed since I don't have a formal EE background.

For context: the project is a solar-powered RasPi system with a pushbutton/e-ink interface which controls motor-actuated valves.

[Edited per comments to clean up wiring:]
[image]

Also hope this schematic might be useful to anyone building solar-powered RPi stuff.

(Edit) Datasheets:

- [MCP23017 i2c I/O expander](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf)
- [Ag103 solar charge circuit](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1048/Ag103_datasheet_Solar_Panel_Battery_Charge_Control-1804315.pdf)
- [TB6612FNG quad half-bridge](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TB6612FNG_datasheet_en_20141001-708260.pdf)
- [SPI e-ink display](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/interfacing/Interfacing_e-Paper_%20Display_Module_to_Raspberry_Pi.pdf)

Comment: Just one remark on the schematic style: long lines snaking around like a labyrinth are hard to follow. Can you tell at first glance what the negative battery terminal connects to? It's better to split your schematic into neat little functional islands, and name the signals that enter/leave each island just like you do for GND and VCC. This will also give you more freedom to arrange the parts in a way that's instantly recognisable, with VCC at the top, GND at the bottom and a left to right reading direction (which would make it more obvious that the buttons have a pull up and low pass filter).

Comment: Ah didn't know you could name non-GND/VCC signals, thanks for the tip!

Comment: looking a lot better now and I can see you fixed a few things already ;) What you can also do is give functional names, eg rename GP02 to SDA1 and GP10 to SDA2, GP23 to STAT_SOLAR, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. It's not clear if your PGND/GND should be tied together
   If the P1.1 has isolation then PGND and GND should be separate, if not then they need to be tied together. I can't tell because there is no information on the 3A Buck module

Q1 is a low side switch and is facing the wrong direction (the diode will always conduct even if the switch is off) Current will flow from the PGND to the negative terminal of the battery. The fuse is sufficient to break the connection in the event of a fault.

In addition current can flow in both directions from the ground, during charging it will flow from the negative terminal to ground, if you do really want a switch there, it needs to be bidirectional.

2. If you are powering the RP from the header, it's probably best to use more than one header pin as ground. One header pin has 10's of mΩ of resistance and creates common mode problems if large amounts of current are going through one pin. Use multiple grounding pins (39 and 14 and 9 and 30)

Comment: Thanks for the review!

Re: 1) The DC-DC converter is based on [MP1584](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP1584/document_id/204/) which looks like GND is common. Should I just convert all PGND to GND, or would it be sufficient to let the board tie them together?

Comment: No need to say thanks there are better ways: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Re: Q1, I was trying to use an N-channel FET for reverse polarity protection a la [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva139/slva139.pdf?ts=1622227171042&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). The direction of the diode appears to match the doc but am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Re: 2) Does that mean that it's generally good practice to tie any free ground pins on IC's together? (I've also heard something about "ground loops," is that/will that be a problem by doing this, & something that the EDA software will solve?)

Comment: That document is probably not considering that the circuit is using a charger whereas the above schematic is. 

It's generally a good idea to use one ground in most designs. The battery ground still needs to be separate in this design or the charge controller can't measure current (it does so through the low side or ground) so it's probably good to keep the battery ground separate. The EDA software will do what you tell it to do, layout and rules are handled by the designer. If there is a situation where two different grounds are tied together, this is done on the schematic with a 'net tie'